# How to interpret $\nabla g(x,y)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}<0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $g\in C_1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$. Suppose that
>
> $$ \nabla g(x,y)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}<0 $$
>
> for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x^2+y^2=1$. Show that there exist
>   $x_*,y_*\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_*^2+y_*^2≤1$ and $\nabla g(x_*,y_*)=0$.

I don't know how to interpret the condition; I thought maybe we could consider a composition of functions such that $\nabla g(x,y)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ would be the differential calculated with the chain rule, but this doesn't seem possible...

Please only hints on how to tackle it!

Comment: you mean $x_\ast^2 +y_\ast^2 <1$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $C^1$ function has to have some local maxima over the unit disk.
Since it/they cannot lie on the boundary...

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret that expression as the dot product between the gradient of $g$ and the positionvector.
$$
\nabla g(x,y)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = x\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)+y\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y)
$$

Comment: That is the definition. The interpretation is "in a neighbourhood of $x^2+y^2=1$, the function is radially decreasing".